# How to transfer motion between these two parts?

Tags: robotic-arm, mechanism, servomotor

I'm trying to model this arm and I'm having a problem knowing what way could I use to make the red part always parallel to the surface of the table [image]

Comment: this structure does exactly what you want .... https://4dmaniac.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/pixar-angle-poise-desk-lamp.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a [4 bar linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-bar_linkage).  When opposite links are equal in length, they stay parallel.